# Functional implementation (e.g. in Haskell) of GoF's Lexi Editor application

Tags: oop, haskell, functional-programming, design-patterns

I am trying to understand how one can use functional programming to implement applications which are usually implemented using an OO/imperative-approach.

One important category of applications is editors (Word, Evernote, PowerPoint, Photoshop etc).

Let's consider GoF's [Lexi](https://code.google.com/p/jexieditor/) Editor application as a representative and well-known example whose object-oriented/imperative solution has been described in great detail in the GoF book.

How would one write the equivalent of GoF's Lexi application in Haskell ?

Would that be possible at all ? How would the time/memory complexity compare in the OO/imperative vs. FP/immutable approaches ?

What would the general architecture of that application (Lexi) be when implemented in Haskell ?

How would it be better or worse than the non-functional/object-oriented solution described in the GoF book ?

Thanks for reading.

EDIT/ANSWER:

The book '**The Haskell School of Expression**' seems to answer this question. It shows (among other things) how to develop a graphical editor in Haskell.

EDIT 2 : [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLj1QV11o9g) presentation seems to also answer this question (not directly though).

Comment: This question seems a little off-topic for stack overflow. My experience with design patterns is that they fall into one of two groups. They are either just a single data type or they are a component that can't be described generically in code, so instead there's an English description of how to make the component generically. Better abstractions available in languages with more expressive power allow more of the latter group to become programming components in their own right.

Comment: Your question invites answerers to explain how to develop an entire application and do a compare-and-contrast with its counterpart in another language. It seems you find it hard to imagine what it's like on the other side of the paradigm shift; to find out, first learn the new paradigm wholeheartedly.

Comment: Would it be impossible to answer this question ? I don't think so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll address your one question which has an objective answer:

> Would [writing the equivalent of GoF's Lexi application in Haskell] be possible at all ? How would the time/memory complexity compare in the OO/imperative vs. FP/immutable approaches ?

Yes, it would be possible. There are no inherent time/memory complexity constraints in Haskell compared to "OO/imperitive approaches", if you admit something as simple as the [ST monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-ST.html). Without the ST monad, it's an [open problem whether purely functional languages with lazy evaluation can achieve the same time performance as mutable languages](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Open_research_problems). They are certainly within a time performance factor of `log(M)` where `M` is the amount of memory used in the mutable system; this can be easily seen by building a mutable memory system out of a tree.

Comment: Also, in the imperative programming model one assumes that random memory access is O(1). One might argue that this is incorrect, asymptotically speaking, since physical memory access still requires passing through log(M) logic gates. If you account for this, then the tree-based memory representation one can have in a funcitonal language does not look so bad.